# Native Crash | abort | libc.so | android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*)

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

Below is the log that i captured from Google Play console, that seem to be occurring in major number.
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash did not help much.

What may cause this error?
I am unable to reproduce this issue. but occurs in good number in production. (However I have not  tried in all devices)

**Devices in which this observed:**
Huawei P30 Pro (HWVOG), Android 9
Huawei HUAWEI Y9 Prime 2019 (HWSTK-HF), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy S9 (starlte), Android 9
Huawei P30 Pro (HWVOG), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy Note9 (crownlte), Android 9
Huawei P30 Pro (HWVOG), Android 9
Samsung Galaxy Note10+ (d2s), Android 9
Huawei Mate 20 Pro (HWLYA), Android 9
Huawei HUAWEI Y9 Prime 2019 (HWSTK-HF), Android 9 
Huawei Mate 20 Pro (HWLYA), Android 9 
Huawei HUAWEI P30 lite (HWMAR), Android 9

**Error From Google Play Console**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000022988  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
  #01  pc 0000000000008480  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+304)
  #02  pc 000000000000be14  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+168)
  #03  pc 000000000006c05c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::processPendingDerefs()+104)
  #04  pc 000000000006c16c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+52)
  #05  pc 000000000009ff60  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 000000000000fa94  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
  #07  pc 00000000000bc8e0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 0000000000083588  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #09  pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```